# HIVE SQL create statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user.name_visits(
    date1 TIMESTAMP,
    MV String,
    visits_by_MV int
)
COMMENT ‘visits_at_MV’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
;
```

It is saying error near BY

Comment: Your have curly single quotes in your question.  These would not be handled as single quotes by Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Below query worked for me..

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user.name_visits(

date1 TIMESTAMP,

MV STRING,

visits_by_MV INT

)

COMMENT 'visits_at_MV'

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

;

> Error you are seeing could be because of the editor you are using.
>   
> If you look at your Quotation marks.. they're LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK and RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.
>   
> Only change I made was using an APOSTROPHE.
>
> Try this way it should work

Answer (score 0):

Change single quotes with double as below:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user.name_visits(
    date1 TIMESTAMP,
    MV String,
    visits_by_MV int
)
COMMENT "visits_at_MV"
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
;